# Filtering orders by Postcode

Tags: search, magento2.2.7

In the UK, we refer to our postcodes as either "`SW1A 0AA`" or "`SW1A0AA`" (with/without spaces).

The issue with this, is that when you Filter your Orders by Shipping Address (backend Sales Order Grid) you get 2 different results depending on whether you enter "`SW1A 0AA`" or "`SW1A0AA`".

[image]

Is there a wildcard or other method I could implement that would allow either entry to return the same results?

Comment: show us the code how you currently do the filter, because there are multiple ways to do this. or are you talking about the adminhtml?

Comment: The filter I'm referring to is a core function - Not something I've made. I've updated my answer to reflect that it's a backend search.

Comment: I'm sorry to tell you that this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento 2 out-of-box functionality does not allow filtering a postcode with different variations of additional characters or white spaces. It is basically what you typed, what you get approach.

Magento 2 Sales Order Grid is based on the UI Component functionality. Part of that, the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool` class is used to provide an extension point for filtering purposes. With this in mind, additional applier classes that represent custom logic to help form collection filters can be used.

We can see, how this class is configured inside the `vendor/magento/module-sales/etc/di.xml` configuration file.

```
<type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="regular" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter</item>
            <item name="fulltext" xsi:type="object">Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FulltextFilter</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Here is the implementation of the `Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\RegularFilter::apply()` method.

```
public function apply(Collection $collection, Filter $filter)
{
    $collection->addFieldToFilter($filter->getField(), [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]);
}
```

This is what the Shipping Address and Postcode fields search queries use in order to filter a collection of orders.

It means, that in order to provide custom logic for the Shipping Address search function, we should implement our own applier class and introduce the logic that will help to show orders for both postcode values including "SW1A 0AA" or "SW1A0AA".

### Solution

The Postcode applier class can look like the below:

```
<?php declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Pronko\Postcode\UiComponent\DataProvider;

use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection;
use Magento\Framework\Api\Filter;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterApplierInterface;

class PostcodeFilter implements FilterApplierInterface
{
    /**
     * @param Collection $collection
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @throws LocalizedException
     */
    public function apply(Collection $collection, Filter $filter)
    {
        if ($this->isPostCodeField($filter)) {
            $postCodeCondition = $this->getPostCodeCondition($filter);
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($this->getPostCodeField($filter, $postCodeCondition), $postCodeCondition);
        } else {
            $collection->addFieldToFilter($filter->getField(), [$filter->getConditionType() => $filter->getValue()]);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @return bool
     */
    private function isPostCodeField(Filter $filter): bool
    {
        return 'postcode' === substr($filter->getField(), -8);
    }

    /**
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPostCodeCondition(Filter $filter): array
    {
        $postcodes = $this->getPostCodeValues($filter->getValue());

        $result = [];
        foreach ($postcodes as $key => $value) {
            $result['key_' . $key] = [$filter->getConditionType() => sprintf('%%%s%%', $value)];
        }
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param string $postcode
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPostCodeValues(string $postcode): array
    {
        $cleanPostcode = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9]/", '', $postcode);
        $cleanPostcode = strtoupper($cleanPostcode);

        $result[] = $cleanPostcode;
        if (strlen($cleanPostcode) === 5) {
            $postcode = substr($cleanPostcode, 0, 2) . ' ' . substr($cleanPostcode, 2, 3);
        } elseif (strlen($cleanPostcode) === 6) {
            $postcode = substr($cleanPostcode, 0, 3) . ' ' . substr($cleanPostcode, 3, 3);
        } elseif (strlen($cleanPostcode) === 7) {
            $postcode = substr($cleanPostcode, 0, 4) . ' ' . substr($cleanPostcode, 4, 3);
        }
        $result[] = $postcode;
        return $result;
    }

    /**
     * @param Filter $filter
     * @param $condition
     * @return array
     */
    private function getPostCodeField(Filter $filter, $condition): array
    {
        $result = [];
        foreach (array_keys($condition) as $key) {
            $result[$key] = $filter->getField();
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

The `apply()` method will check that the filter name is a field, we are looking for. It should match the **postcode** value. The name of the filter can also include additional prefix information, we should just skip it for the purpose of finding the postcode.

The `getPostCodeCondition()` method returns a list of 2 postcode values, with and without space inside. For the UK postcodes, it is very important to find the right length of a postcode field.

Finally, in order to add the right amount of fields into the `addFieldToFilter()`, we use the `getPostCodeField()` method to return the correct keys and field names.

The `Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\AbstractDb::addFieldToFilter()` method will check that we pass 2 fields and 2 conditions and form the MySQL OR condition with the same name of the field and 2 values for the postcode.

The next step is to add this applier into the FilterPool list of applier via the `Pronko\Postcode\etc\di.xml` configuration file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\DataProvider\FilterPool">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="appliers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="like" xsi:type="object">Pronko\Postcode\UiComponent\DataProvider\PostcodeFilter</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

After cleaning config cache with `bin/magento cache:clean config` command, the new filtering logic should work.